# How to get a tank (Rhino) at the beginning?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I went all the way to Area 69 to find out the tank is not there. What are other spawns where I can get a tank at the beginning of the game, that is when the roads are all blocked?

**Update**

- According to [WikiGTA](http://en.wikigta.org/wiki/Rhino_location_%28GTA_San_Andreas%29), the Rhino is only available at Area 69 after Verdant Meadows mission.

Comment: If you're not above cheating, I seem to remember there being a key combination that spawns a tank, regardless of where you are...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [GTA Wiki](http://gta.wikia.com/Rhino), there are 4 ways to get the Rhino:

> Available inside Area 69, but when the base is entered 5 stars wanted level is automatically gained, so don't try to get it until after obtaining the Verdant Meadows safehouse; make a run for it once you get the tank and save to eliminate the stars before parking the Rhino in the hangar.
>
> Will spawn underneath the bridge going above Ganton after 100% is achieved.
>
> Can be spawned by typing the code "aiwprton" during gameplay.
>
> Police will use the tank to stop you once you achieved 6 stars. Save when it comes to clear wanted, try to steal and kill the person inside.

That means that the only way to get it early in the game (and without cheat codes) is by achieving 6 stars, but with the weak disposable weapons you have it will be very hard to get 6 stars and survive long enough to hijack the Rhino.

Comment: I think it is also impossible to get to 6 stars in the beginning

Answer (score 2):

Max out your wanted level (the stars). You'll get tanks coming after you shortly at that point. However, you can only get all 6 wanted stars when you are fairly far in the game.

Area 69 is the only place in the game the Rhino spawns normally.

Comment: That's one way but it removes all the fun of crossing the border, have all the cops after you, steal the tank then make it shoot the other way to cross the river. =/ Is the Area 69 really the only place a Rhino spawns?

Comment: @Renan, o my mistake. I was lazy and read only your title, and answered that. I apologize, I hadn't realized you were asking for 'spawns'. Area 69 is the only spawn point.

Comment: Well you did answer the question correctly. I'll leave it open for a while in case someone comes up with something but I guess raising wanted level is the only way.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to get 6stars ...and live to enjoy it. First you NEED to be at CJ s (as you walk outside go immediately to the left. On to the porch. It will provide a lot of protection) . Having completed gang tags will give you ammo support for when you run inside you can reload. And using malotov will help a lot . This is just part of it.... While on the porch start shooting. Don't forget to crouch for cover. If things get too crazy or out of ammo. Duck inside. Reload repeat till tanks show, or till a tank is left behind from after you save... That's how I do it. PC seems a little more stubborn to show tanks though.