# What is the fastest way to raise your wanted level?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I want a tank, Rhino, and I haven't finished the mission that triggers the game to spawn it at Area 69. After searching about other spawns and [asking about it here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81108), it turns out that's the only spawn other than [above Ganton](http://gta.wikia.com/Rhino#Locations), which requires 100% completion.

So what is the fastest way to get 6 stars wanted level in order to finally steal a Rhino?

Comment: I seem to remember that the army won't show up to fight you right from the start - you have to get to a certain point in the campaign first.  If you seem to wanted-level plateau and can't get any higher, you may be out of luck :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blow up police cars. Simple as that, blow up as many police cars\vehicles (IE: The swat SUVS) as you can as fast as possible.

The best way to do this specifically is probably to try, the best you can, to stay in a small area as you gather your wanted level. When you get multiple vehicles in the same area, use grenades or some other explosive to start the classic chain reaction of one explosion to another to another.

Comment: I played a LOT of San Andreas in my time. heheheh.

Comment: @Renan hit back with if you were successfull or not, I've never attempted getting a tank so early in the game, and I'd be interested to know if you accomplished the feat.

Comment: I've been trying for a while and even after dropping four choppers the wanted level never went over four stars.

Comment: @Renan Thats interesting, I will investigate this. You have tripped a latent memory that you may NOT be able to acheive more than 4 stars until a certain point in the game. I hope I am incorrect, I'll get back to you.

Comment: I confirmed it's not possible, at least for now, by using the cheat code UZUMYMW. I'd still like to know what is the earliest point in which you can get 6 stars. Do you think I should change the question to that?

Comment: @Renan I think you should ask that as an entirely new question.

Answer (score -1):

So what u ca do is after u get to the 3rd city, finish all pilot school missions(first all bronze to get rustler,then all silver to get stunt plane ,last to get all gold to get the hunter/apache millnitary helli)then u can use the hunter(only spawns if u arrive from the west)to blow up all planes near u,get two or three stars blow up some police cars then if other hellicopters arrive. Just keep on fighting them until u get 6 stars and meanwhile try not to get wasted